# Duckdb query plan parse to json

Tags: python, sql, duckdb

Is there a better way to export data from the duckdb in sql? The default is to export to a pretty print format with boxes and details on each.

[Duckdb Explain docs](https://duckdb.org/docs/guides/meta/explain.html)

I am currently running the following script to parse to json.

```
import json

def extract_boxes(text) -> list[list[str]]:
    lines = text.split('\n')
    boxes = []
    visited = set()

    for i in range(len(lines)):
        for j in range(len(lines[i])):
            if lines[i][j] == '┌' and (i, j) not in visited:
                # Find the bottom-left corner of the box
                for x in range(i + 1, len(lines)):
                    if lines[x][j] == '└':
                        break

                # Find the top-right corner of the box
                for y in range(j + 1, len(lines[i])):
                    if lines[i][y] == '┐':
                        break

                # Extract the box content
                box_content = [line[j+1:y] for line in lines[i+1:x]]
                boxes.append('\n'.join(box_content))

                # Mark the corners as visited
                visited.add((i, j))
                visited.add((i, y))
                visited.add((x, j))
                visited.add((x, y))
    for i in range (10):
        boxes = [box.replace('  ', ' ').replace('\u2500','') for box in boxes]
    return [[element.strip() for element in box.split('\n') if element.strip()] for box in boxes]

def list_to_dict(boxes):
    result = []
    for box in boxes:
        if box:
            step_type = box[0].strip()
            details = []
            ec = None
            
            for item in box[1:]:
                if "EC:" in item:
                    ec = item.split("EC:")[1].strip()
                else:
                    details.append(item) # You can populate this with actual values if available
            result.append({
                'StepType': step_type,
                'EstimatedCost': ec,
                'Details': details
            })
    return result

def parse_plan_to_json(text: str) -> str:
    boxes = extract_boxes(text.encode('utf-8', 'ignore').decode('utf-8'))
    return json.dumps(list_to_dict(boxes))
```

I want to have more detailed information about what is in each box.
Am I missing something in the api?

Answer (score 0):

Through the PRAGMA statement you can enable json logging of the query profile:
[PRAGMA duckdb docs](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/pragmas)

```
conn = duckdb.connect(str(database_path))
conn.execute("PRAGMA enable_profiling = 'json';")
conn.execute(f"PRAGMA profiling_output='{str(profile_path)}';")
conn.execute(query)
conn.execute("PRAGMA disable_profiling;")
conn.close()
```

This includes the structure of the query.

The SQL should be valid in all duckdb apis (C, R, ect.)